# Mono Form.Show from another form doesn't work

Tags: forms, asynchronous, mono, show, showdialog

I am trying to port a WinForms app for use with Mono, and I've recently noted that calling Form.Show() from another form will either do nothing or cause the new form to flash and disappear. I read something about the new form needing a message pump, which is accomplished with Application.Run(), but that's already been called. Any idea why this doesn't work? I can't use ShowDialog because my program relies on events fired by completed async tasks, and I don't want to block a ton of extra threads that will be done right after the Show call.

Comment: This isn't really on topic, but it wouldn't really be accepted where it would be.  You need more information, at least a reasonable section of the code, and since this is about mono it probably needs more information about platform.

Comment: If it behaves differently than WinForms in Windows running on .NET, it is a bug in Mono. File it here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hide your current form before showing/displaying your new one?

Seems to me like your form is indeed being displayed but for some strange reason it's being delegated to the background. Worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, whether the calling form is hidden or not, the form being shown completely dissapears after flashing. It doesn't even leave a taskbar icon behind.